# Update Mongo Collection Using hadoop-mongo & PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using mongo-hadoop project and Using PIG to achieve the below.

Right now, i have 2 pig LOAD statements, both has catid as common field all other fields are unique. I want 1 record to be created but with fields from both.

**For example:**

```
Collection1: { catid, key1, key2 }

Collection2: { catid, key3, key4 }
```

and the output to be stored in mongo collection as:

```
_id, catid, key1, key2, key3, key4.
```

I tried:

```
STORE A INTO '$DB.tablename' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoStorage('update [catid]','{catid:1},{unique:false}');

STORE B INTO '$DB.tablename' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoStorage('update [catid]','{catid:1},{unique:false}');
```

but it always inserts. A, B has 10 records having common catid, the output in mongo is 20 records. It doesnt upsert. Any help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use MongoUpdateStorage:

https://github.com/alabid/mongo-hadoop/blob/issues/pig/mongo-update-storage/pig/README.md

Works like a charm